# Dataset - duplicate values when setting primary key

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

I have a dataset with a column "person_code".

This column contains the following data:

- "Carra"
- "Carra " -> one trailing space

Now if i set the primary key of the dataset to the column "person_code" I'll get the following error:

"These columns don't currently have unique values."

Any way around this? The best I can think of is to add a new column "primary_key" and then replace the ending/starting spaces with another sign. This will cause some extra problems: if I replace them with _ and there's already a Carra_ in the database...

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why would you want to allow trailing spaces in a primary key column?  I know it's strictly correct that "Carra" and "Carra " are distinct values, but it's a recipe for confusion, at best.

Comment: Well, our application strips the codes.
A third party application does not strip them. So we're stuck with them.

Comment: FWIW, I am in the same situation.  I inherited data with the same pattern of trailing blanks in one of the rows, and I think it is a bug that DataSet.PrimaryKey throws this exception, when SQL Server accepted this data as valid for a primary key column, when the record was created.  If it was a problem, it should have been flagged then.

Comment: Actually, the table did not have the column set as the primary key, so that is probably why SQL Server accepted the equivalent both of this example's "Carra" and "Carra ".  Only my code is setting DataSet.PrimaryKey on this column, so of course there are no guarantees that the data is really unique.

Answer (score 1):

This is a database schema question, and the answer to your question is that as you have described it the `person_code` column is not suitable as a primary key, as its values are not unique.

Your primary key should be 100% unique - usually an incrementally generated number is a suitable choice.

Comment: The values *are* 100% unique. They do have a unique constraint in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Primary keys are ALWAYS unique, so if two person have the same person code then this will indeed cause this problem

Now, it seems that they are not entirely identical (as you say one has a trailing space. My guess is that your code may remove the trailing space by default. You might want to put a symbol at the start and at the end, like 'Carra' and 'Carra ' to make them different.

You may need to define another symbole that that though. Try one that you know will never be in your data.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new primary key field, preferably with an int or uniqueidentifier for the data type is the suggested solution for your problem and long term maintenance of your database.

Trailing spaces in a value, in general, are a bad idea. both from a UI perspective, but also regarding data integrity. You may consider cleansing the data, stripping leading and trailing spaces, special chars, etc from your data.