# DataTable case sensitive characters on Primary Key

Tags: .net, datatable, unique, primary-key, uppercase

I am in the following situation :

I have to patch a problem in a **very poorly designed** application. In the code, the previous developer get informations from DB and put it in a `DataTable`. Then, he sets `Primary Key` on a field of this datatable.

However, the PK column is **varchar** type, and I have the following error :

> These columns don't currently have unique values.

This is because in the data, I have :

> 123b
>   123B

It seems these values are identical for the datatable, whereas they are not exactly the same.
Is there any quick and dirty workaround to avoid this problem, like `CaseSensitive = False`

PS : I already see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783415/dataset-duplicate-values-when-setting-primary-key), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584916/datatable-hit-case-sensitive-unique-constraint-when-add-new-row), but I'd like to avoid to recreate the entire application...
I know I should create an identity column and set it as PK, but there are a lot of collateral issues and I'll do it only if I can't find a fast solution.

FYI, the datatable is constructed like that :

```
Dim dataColumn As New DataColumn(ucStatus.CheckColumnKey, GetType(Boolean))
dataColumn.DefaultValue = False
dataColumn.AllowDBNull = False
sourceInt.Columns.Add(dataColumn)
sourceInt.Columns(dataColumn.ColumnName).SetOrdinal(0)

sourceInt.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {sourceInt.Columns(MyColumn)}
```

The last line is a problem a `MyColumn` column contains the problematic datas.
The code is in VB.NET, but C# answer is accepted !

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Setting the CaseSensitive property on the DataTable object to true before assigning the PrimaryKey property will allow you to use a PrimaryKey that considers the two values, 123b and 123B, to be unique.  I had the same problem and answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584916/datatable-hit-case-sensitive-unique-constraint-when-add-new-row/29968170#29968170)